# Android RecyclerView EndlessScroll ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-progressbar

I'm trying to add ProgressBar to the bottom of the list while loading next page. How can do it? Is there a way to place my progressbar more efficiently? I saw many uses viewtype in adapter, but i don't really get how it changes. Also, after progressbar ended and new page added, i want the bottom item to scroll for 1 position below.

This is my **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:progress="1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#ccc"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is my **MyAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.service.autofill.Dataset;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    Context c;
    ArrayList<String> id;
    ArrayList<String> name;
    ArrayList<String> email;
    ArrayList<String> phone;

    private Activity mactivity;

    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

    private boolean isLoading;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> id, ArrayList<String> name, ArrayList<String> email, ArrayList<String> phone) {
        this.c = c;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email= email;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("viewType", "onCreateViewHolder: "+viewType);
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.id.setText(id.get(position));
        holder.name.setText(name.get(position));
        holder.email.setText(email.get(position));
        holder.phone.setText(phone.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return id.size();
    }
}
```

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String URL = "myURL.php";
    private String token = "mytoken";

    RecyclerView mrecyclerView;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> email = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> phone = new ArrayList<>();

    String next_page="";

    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Parcelable recyclerViewState;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mProgressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerview);
        mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        new getJSON().execute();

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), id, name, email, phone);

        mrecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                if (URL != null) {
                    //mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recyclerViewState = mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
                            URL = next_page;
                            new getJSON().execute();
                        }
                    }, 200);
                    //mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private class getJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            super.onPostExecute(v);
            mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
            mrecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HTTPHandler httpHandler = new HTTPHandler();
            String json = httpHandler.makeCall(URL, token);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    next_page = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("next_page_url"));

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        id.add(obj.getString("id"));
                        name.add(obj.getString("name"));
                        email.add(obj.getString("email"));
                        phone.add(obj.getString("phone"));
                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

and i used  **EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java** from [here](https://github.com/shandilyaaman/SampleEndlessRecyclerView/blob/master/SampleEndlessRecyclerView/endlessrecyclerview/src/main/java/com/endlessrecyclerview/android/EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java)

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
//    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
     */
    private int mPreviousTotal=0;
    /**
     * True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
     */
    private boolean mLoading = true;

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        int visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (mLoading) {
            if (totalItemCount > mPreviousTotal) {
                mLoading = false;
                mPreviousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        int visibleThreshold = 5;
        if (!mLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            onLoadMore();

            mLoading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are you sure still you have this error ?! because all of `//mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` commented!! if still you have this error please show me where is it on your code

Answer (score 0):

This progressbar should be added in your activity's xml and not in `list_item.xml` but it is not.  
So with this line in your activity class:

```
mProgressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
```

the variable `mProgressBar` is `null` because it cannot be found inside the activity's xml.  
So move the below code from `list_item.xml` to `activity_main.xml`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:progress="1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```